# Accepted answer that you don't agree with during review audit

Tags: discussion, answers, review-audits

As I was going through and reviewing posts, I saw [this one](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/576112).

I downvoted it and then got this message:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality
>   post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

For some reason, this answer got plenty of upvotes and was accepted.  However, I think this answer is more of a joke than a solution that people like and find humorous.  This solution did block the view, but it did not disable the input from the webcam, which was the question.

I don't think placing a piece of tape, or band-aid on your computer is a valid solution.  If someone posted a question saying their capslock doesn't work, and I posted an answer saying to put a weight on the shift key as a solution, I'm pretty sure my answer would not be accepted.

I completely disagree with this answer and I'm not happy that this was an audited question that I "failed".  What can I do in this situation?  What does this audit failure mean?  And how can I disagree with this joke answer without just upsetting the people who found it funny and upvoted it?  As a professional, I think this should be fixed, and I would probably be fired if I gave this solution to my boss.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the response and there should be a comment you can make directly to the audit.  The accepted answer and the up votes are ridiculous

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is technically a valid solution, there are even whole ranges of products you can buy to do this exact thing but I agree, it is not a great answer from a technical stand point.

The thing is, people can vote for what ever they like, even the OP accepted it. Audits are automatic, so I doubt there is much anyone can do, it was not tampered with and the community voted it up.

The best advice I can give you is, if in doubt, look at the original question.

Audits aren't about you been right or wrong, just paying attention, so looking at the original post is a valid way of showing attention.

I don't think it can be reversed but don't worrie, you have to fail a few in quick succession for it to affect your account.

This was just bad luck.

Answer (score 17):

The only way to disagree is to downvote the answer. Personally, I think it is an excellent answer that gives the only reasonable solution to a rather silly question. It is certainly the simplest, most obvious and most foolproof solution even if it isn't technical. The fact that it's a hardware solution (so to speak) and not a software one doesn't make it a bad answer.

As for the review audit, ignore it. Failing a few is no big deal. It happens to all of us. In fact, you can expect to fail more. The system chooses the audit posts based on votes and votes are a very poor measure of quality. They're just the best we have.