# Failed first post audit by flagging as a duplicate. Is it correct?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, review-audits

While reviewing the first posts queue, I failed the following audit: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/799873

After I looked at the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993160/how-to-find-required-information-in-man), I just thought: “That must have been answered already” and quickly found [another (a few days older) question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands?rq=1) with the same topic. Searching the manpage contents isn’t the main topic there but it is answered well in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/991947/250300). So I flagged the question as a duplicate but the system declined it.

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality
>   post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

Is flagging an upvoted question as a duplicate considered bad?

Comment: Related: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15533/accepted-answer-that-you-dont-agree-with-during-review-audit?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just a duplicate that went hot before anybody found the dupe. The audit system frowns on downvoting or closing posts it picked as examples of *good* posts, even if they are legitimate actions. It's dumb, but, it is what it is and what it is is difficult to improve.

I'd suggest that you always click the *link* to the post to verify you're shown the actual post. If it's different in some details - author, score - it's an audit and you do whatever it expects of you.

Comment: This is a problem with the audit system that should be fixed... there should be some way to dispute bad audits cleanly.

Comment: @vidarlo: After a year or so here, you can smell them from a mile away _and even then you will still fail some dumb one like the one in the question above every now and then!_  Who cares about a single failed audit?  As long as you don't fail too many and get banned from reviewing?  Puh!  **:-) :-) :-)**

Comment: @fabby which happend to me a week ago:D

Comment: Yeah, happened to me too in the past, so I took a break, came back and nog when I fail one, I actually sit, back, relax and think and swear a lot most of the time and when I see something that is fishy, I open the original in a new tab ens see what it looks like and vote what they system thinks I should be voting... @vidarlo

Comment: @vidarlo a system for disputing bad audits sounds like a good idea, you should take it to meta.stackexchange